# Peferred way to call AWS Api Gateway using PHP

Tags: php, rest, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

The AWS Api gateway generate SDK for JS, Swift and Android (Java) by default. So I want to call to the AWS Api Gateway using PHP, besides hand coding the HTTP request, are there any better choice?

Comment: Perhaps this? https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/  Googling for AWS and PHP brought up several resources.

Answer (score 0):

While you will not have modeled classes, the [AWS SDK for PHP v3](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/) can be used to call/sign API Gateway APIs.

Comment: can you share some small snippet on how can we call an API from php?

Comment: Would also appreciate a snippet.

Answer (score 0):

I had reasonably good success with [swagger.io](https://editor.swagger.io). Log into the API Gateway, export your Swagger definitions in YAML, paste them into the editor and then you can generate the PHP client from the site.